# Get single QuerySet object from two different models using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-orm

My First models

```
class UserModel(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
profile_pic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)
college_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
user_id = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
user_password = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'user'
```

Second Model

```
class GroupPostCommentsModel(models.Model):
comment_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
comment_by_user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
post_id = models.ForeignKey(GroupPostsModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'group_posts_comments'
```

I want data as follows :
[id,first_name, last_name, profile_pic, comment_text, likes]

My Serializer

```
class GroupPostCommentsSerializerGetInfo(serializers.Serializer):
id = serializers.IntegerField()#it is primary key of GroupPostCommentsModel
comment_text = serializers.CharField(max_length=1000)
likes = serializers.IntegerField(default=0)
time_stamp = serializers.DateTimeField(default='')
first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)# From UserModel
last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)# From UserModel
profile_pic = serializers.ImageField(default='')# From UserModel
```

first_name, last_name, profile_pic : from UserModel
comment_text, likes : from GroupPostCommentsModel

python3 --version
Python 3.6.9

Django==3.2.10

I am stuck in the project for a long time please help. :)

Comment: Cann you share the models and how you want to use the result of the query?

Comment: my need result as : select first_name, last_name, profile_pic, comment_text, likes from user , group_post_comments where post_id = 1;

Comment: *****select first_name, last_name, profile_pic, comment_text, likes from user , group_post_comments where user.id = group_posts_comments.comment_by_user && post_id = 1;

Comment: Hi, Iain Shelvington can you please help me..?

Comment: A user could have multiple comments per post, do you want your returned data to contain repeated data for each user comment? Can you show how you want to use this data in a template or serializer?

Comment: Yes, I want to return data to contain repeated data for each customer. I add a serializer in the post please check. Actually, I am developing a comment section in my project using Django. Hii lain Shelvington  I am Waiting for your response ...!